# Choosing between Class, Interface, Types for conditional models

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, model

I do use Angular 8 with TS 3.5. I create and receive objects from the BE and it often gives me type error because a property doesn't exist. What's the best to init an object with a type you don't know in advance ?

Imagine (really simplified) :

```
export enum UnitTypeEnum {
  COMMERCIAL = 'COMMERCIAL',
  RESIDENTIAL = 'RESIDENTIAL'
}

export class RentModel {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

export class UnitModel extends RentModel {
  type: UnitTypeEnum;
  ...
  ...
}

export class ResidentialModel extends UnitModel {
  houseType: string;
}

export class CommercialModel extends UnitModel {
  surface: number;
}
```

Then in a form :

```
const unitViewModel = new UnitModel();

  if (this.selectedUnitType === UnitTypeEnum.RESIDENTIAL) {

    (unitViewModel as ResidentialModel).houseType = this.unitForm.get('main.houseType').value;

  }
```

I don't know in advance if the unitViewModel will be Commercial or Residential.
Should I use class, interface, types for ResidentialModel or CommercialModel ?
What is the best way to proceed to avoid many 'XXXMODEL as XXXMODEL' ?

Thank you for your help and advices.

Comment: If you don't know the type then you may use `any` as the type. e.g., `unitViewModel : any`, `price: any` etc.,

Comment: Sure but no need for Typscript with `any` everywhere.

Comment: The key thing here is to avoid classes to represent the type of deserialize data because. It doesn't matter if you use a type or an interface

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use interfaces, that have one common property e.g. type and then you can create a Union type for all interfaces:

```
export enum UnitTypeEnum {
  COMMERCIAL = 'COMMERCIAL',
  RESIDENTIAL = 'RESIDENTIAL'
}

interface RentModel {
  type: UnitTypeEnum;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

interface ResidentialModel extends RentModel {
  houseType: string;
}

interface CommercialModel extends RentModel {
  surface: number;
}

type UnitedType = ResidentialModel | CommercialModel;

let residential: UnitedType = {
  type: UnitTypeEnum.RESIDENTIAL,
  name: 'Resodential',
  price: 100,
  houseType: 'house'
}

let commercial: UnitedType = {
  type: UnitTypeEnum.COMMERCIAL,
  name: 'Commercial',
  price: 100,
  surface: 200
}

if (residential.type === UnitTypeEnum.RESIDENTIAL) {
  console.log(residential.houseType);
}

if (commercial.type === UnitTypeEnum.COMMERCIAL) {
  console.log(commercial.surface);
}
```

code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2pxzbe?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks for example. Good solution to avoid Union Types everywhere. But when you init an object with future unknowm value (let's say not knowing type of commercial/residential in advance), you still get locked. Here is your exemple modified : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fxmsqa . But don't think there is a way, it's just typescript (and normal in some way to only give option if properties exist on both interface).